# PHP условия в зависимости от значений чисел (1.0, 0.1, 0.01)

Tags: php, if

Всем привет!

Столкнулся в процессе работы с задачкой, где нужно в зависимости от условий отображать количество символов после точки. Пояснения, ниже :)

**Если, есть целое число (до точки), обрезать до 2 после точки:**

Число: 1.565445444888700 — Результат: 1.56
Число: 163.1190000000000 — Результат: 163.11

**Если, есть десятичное число (любое кроме нуля), обрезать до 6 после точки:**

Число: 0.436521540000000 — Результат: 0.436521
Число: 0.252804854417770 — Результат: 0.252804

**Все что начинается с сотых (с любого количества нулей), обрезать до 12 после точки:**

Число: 0.000000001293950 — Результат: 0.000000001293
Число: 0.011562555488000 — Результат: 0.011562555488

Пробовал делать что то вроде *«if ($a > '1.1') {»* и *«if ($a < '0.1') {»*, но выходит какая то ерунда. Ну и видимо я конкретно туплю)

Answer (score 0):

Сам создал, сам ответил)) Не знаю пригодится ли кому, но вот:

```
if ($a > '1.0') {
echo 'X.X';
} 
elseif ($a > '0.1') {
echo '0.X';
}
elseif ($a < '0.1') {
echo '0.XX';
}
```

Comment: Меня тут очень смущают строки вместо чисел и какой-то непонятный вывод

Comment: Это никому не пригодится. Эта штука - результат большого везения. Конкретно на этих значениях порядок строк совпадает с порядком чисел. Программирование в стиле "Я попробовал. Работает! Ура!". Как задачка на ненормальное программирование - прикольно.